# How can I use VIM in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, visual-studio

I've scoured the web and can't seem to figure out how to add a VIM extension into the Visual Studio preview for Mac. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug - Use my plugin: [XSVim](https://github.com/nosami/XSVim/releases).

It's now available in the Visual Studio for Mac extension gallery (under IDE extensions).

[image: Visual Studio for Mac extension gallery, Vim]